# Exchange Server 2003 - Register Event Sync - OnSave OnDelete - Exchange Explorer - RegEvent.vbs

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2003

I am trying to add an event sync via the wizard in exchange explorer, that comes from the SDK, to the default public folder calendar without success.

Things I am able to do:
I can Use the event wizard on a test folder in the same node as the default calendar and add event syncs to a com+ app I have registered with the system. This works fine, and all our testing is completed.

Things i cannot do:
In exchange explorer i can navigate to the default public calendar but i cannot see any of the items that are added to that folder.  In exchange explorer I get a message that says “The Schema or Items is not located at the specified server.” See below. In addition if I right click on the node I do not get options to use a event registration wizard I actually don’t get any options.  However on the test node I do.

What I want to do is be able to add an event item to the items node.  Also,  I have rights on the calendar node as administrator with ownership rights on the folder on the client configuration in exchange system manager.

Can someone please let me know what I should do to get the event sync on this top-level folder?  Also, would / should I use the RegEvent script and would I have success with that if there is not success here?

http://ikoios.com/ftp/exchangeerror.png

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is related to Permissions. Try to check it [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd297943.aspx).